# Populate data with result after perform create in mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I want to populate result after save chat data. 
my controller code for chat:

```
exports.addChat = (req, res, next) => {
    Chat.create(req.body).then(result => {
      // Populate data with result like:
       //result.populate({path: 'sender', select: 'user_name full_name image_url' }).populate({path: 'receiver', select: 'user_name full_name image_url' })
       // .then(dt => {
       //
        //}).catch(e => {
        //    console.log(e);
      //  });
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'message created',
            data: result
        });
    }).catch(err=> {
        if(!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
    });
};
```

And Chat schema is:

```
const chatSchema = new Schema({
    sender: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'profile',
        required: true
    },
    receiver: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'profile',
        required: true
    },
    message: {
        type: String
    },
    expire_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now, index: { expires: '86400s' }} 
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Btw, i populate data for get result but want to populate with the return data after save.

Comment: You have commented the query, whats the issue in it?

Comment: AFAIK, populate perform the find and selection for you in a separate query. So, you can just run a separate find query after `create`. The outcome should be the same!

Comment: @Shaharyar , i am trying to populate data in the commented section. but it not work

Comment: @Dijkstra i know. but are you sure that it is unable working after create?